# onPostExecute() not working on re-run of asyncTask called from an activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**First time if I run my application then the control goes to onPostExecute() after doinBackground() is complete .But if I re run the application on the device without uninstalling then onPostExecute() is never executed.**

I have an **activity** from where I am calling my asynTask .

**CODE:**

```
public class AddThing extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
try {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {
startAddThingType2Task();
}
}
private class ThingCallback implements ActionCallback {

        Context cntxt;

        public ThingCallback(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
           this.cntxt = context;    
        }

        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<?> objects) {

            setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DocketDetail.class);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {            
            Toast.makeText(cntxt, "Unable to add docket. Error is: "+ exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }       
    }
private void startAddThingType2Task() {


            final AddThingType2 task = new AddThingType2(AddThing.this,new ThingCallback(this));

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    task.execute();

                }
            });
}
```

My asyncTask Class is:

```
public class AddThingType2Task2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    public ActionCallback callback = null;
    private Context context;
    private Exception ePriv = null;
    private Activity activity;

    public AddThingType2(Activity activity,ActionCallback callback, ) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result == true) {
            callback.onSuccess(null);
        } else {
            callback.onFailure(ePriv);
        }               
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Boolean retval = false;



        try {

            retval = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("AddThingType2Task", e.getMessage());
            ePriv = e;
        }

        return retval;
    }

}
```

**ActionCallback** interface has two methods - `onSuccess()` and `OnFailure()` in it.

**Edit** 
I'm using **commonsware wakeful intent service** also in my application .

For the first time its working like charm but on re-run onpostExecute() not working...

Please help !!

Regards

Upon re-run i am getting this in **logcat** :

```
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311): Handler{4060df08} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{4060df08} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:457)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:430)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:367)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.onStatusChanged(LocationManager.java:206)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:75)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
09-20 17:37:28.515: W/MessageQueue(9311):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you are using `WakefulIntentService`, you have no need for an `AsyncTask`. `IntentService` already gives you a background thread, which `WakefulIntentService` inherits. Your `onHandleIntent()` (`IntentService`) or `doWakefulWork()` (`WakefulIntentService`) is on a background thread. In fact, forking *another* background thread is likely to cause you problems.

Comment: Sir, actually through the `AsyncTask` i am communicating with my `server` when required and is independent of `WakefulIntentService`.

Comment: There is no `onPostExecute()` in a `WakefulIntentService`, and so one will never run. `onPostExecute()` is something from `AsyncTask`. If you are not using `AsyncTask` from a `WakefulIntentService`, then `WakefulIntentService` has nothing to do with your problem. If you *are* using an `AsyncTask` from a `WakefulIntentService`, do not do that.

Comment: Ok sir, but kindly look into my problem for the very first time `onpostExecute` of `AsyncTask` is woking but upon re-run without uninstalling the app its not executed.... i have posted the `logcat` value please check it !

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AddThing extends Activity {
   private ThingCallback callback;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ThingCallback = new ThingCallback(this);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
try {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {
startAddThingType2Task();
}
}
private class ThingCallback implements ActionCallback {
        Context cntxt;

        public ThingCallback(Context context) {
           this.cntxt = context;    
        }

        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<?> objects) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DocketDetail.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {            
            Toast.makeText(cntxt, "Unable to add docket. Error is: "+ exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }       
    }

private void startAddThingType2Task() {
   final AddThingType2 task = new AddThingType2(AddThing.this, callback);
   task.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other Thread then the AsyncTask? If not there is no need to use runOnUiThread. Remove it and don't make the AsyncTask reference final. An AsyncTask can never be executed twice, that's why you have to instantiate it new everytime you use it again. The final keyword will prevent a new instantiation and makes the reference immutable.

```
private void startAddThingType2Task() {
   AddThingType2 task = new AddThingType2(AddThing.this,new ThingCallback(this));
   task.execute();
}
```

If you need the runOnUiThread, consider to declare the AsyncTask instance as a field. That way you don't have to make it final to use it in runOnUiThread.

Edit:

You would have something like this:

```
public class AddThing extends Activity {
        // Your field
        AddThingType2 task;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
            try {
                Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {
            startAddThingType2Task();
        }

        private void startAddThingType2Task() {
            // no final needed and you can instantiate it multiple times
            task = new AddThingType2(AddThing.this, callback);
            task.execute();
        }
}
```

Comment: how to declare the AsyncTask instance as a field ??

Comment: Ok, I can't see what exactly you are doing, because your posted code seems not nearly complete.

Comment: My code is too long... check the **logcat** value in my edit ... i am not using any `handler`.

Answer (score 0):

put this class loading in application's onCreate

```
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application{

   public void onCreate(){
     try {
       Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }
}
```